# How to loop the following code in Python?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I am new to Python but I tried to create the following trading strategy but cannot find a way to loop it for different products (trading hours in this case).

```
def strategy(area_code, product, orders, environment):
    order = None
    new_orders = [] 
    Quantity = 5
    price_delta = 0.1

    def process_flex(Plant):

        order = None
        Tur1 = Plant + "1"

        if Tur1Volume > 0:
            if Tur1Price:
                order = None
                if check_if_we_have_order_on_the_market(Plant,Tur1)==0:
                    order =  package.create_sell_order(area_code, Tur1Volume, Quantity, calculate_selling_price(Tur1Price), price_delta, product, environment.current_datetime).with_label((Plant,Tur1))
                if order:
                    new_orders.append(order)
            else:
                order = None

        return 

    process_flex("bla")
    process_flex("blabla")
    process_flex("blablabla")


    return new_orders
```

This code is only working for one product (1 hour) and does not loop for all 24 products. 
I thought that it could work like this:

```
    for product in products:
        Plant = ['bla', 'blabla', 'blablabla']
        for i in Plant:
            order = process_flex(Plant)
        return_orders.append(order)

    return return_orders
```

Unfortunately, it did not work. Do you have any idea on the solution?

Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: Where is `return_orders` defined? Did you change `new_orders` to `return_orders`? I'm also confused, because in the first code block, you're appending orders to `new_orders` inside of `process_flex()`, and returning None, whereas you're getting a return value from `process_flex()` in the second code block, and then appending that to the list. It would be much easier to see what's happening if we could see the whole `strategy()` function for the second code block.

Comment: If I had to guess without seeing that code though, my first instinct would be to say that 'products' is an empty list. Check the arguments you're passing into `strategy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to swap Plant to :
order = process_flex(i)
because i is an element of Plant

```
    for product in products:
        Plant = ['bla', 'blabla', 'blablabla']
        for i in Plant:
            order = process_flex(i)
        return_orders.append(order)

    return return_orders
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed this small error. However, the problem is still not solved. The code providing no results at all with the loop above. If I erase the loop, it works for one product (hour) but not for all of them.

Comment: From what I can guess, this line should be wrong:
`
if check_if_we_have_order_on_the_market(Plant,Tur1)==0:
`
Here Plant and Tur1 are exactly the same except the fact that you have a "1" at the end of Tur1, so you might want check this condition too.
Otherwise the logic seems good so without more details I won't be able to help